# How to create a rank command with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

lately i have been trying to create a leveling bot with discord.py (without using Cog, with bot.command). The code actually works to update the level after each messages but the rank command doesn't work.
I have a message error like `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Anyone has an idea to fix it please ?

Here is my complete code (json and discord libraries are already imported) :

```
with open("users.json", "ab+") as ab:
    ab.close()
    f = open('users.json','r+')
    f.readline()
    if os.stat("users.json").st_size == 0:
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    else:
      pass
 
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
  users = json.load(f)
 
@bot.event    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await add_experience(users, message.author)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            await bot.process_commands(message)
 
async def add_experience(users, user):
  if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 0
  users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += 6
  print(f"{users[f'{user.id}']['level']}")
 
async def level_up(users, user, message):
  experience = users[f'{user.id}']["experience"]
  lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']["level"]
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send(f':tada: {user.mention} has reached level {lvl_end}. Congrats! :tada:')
    users[f'{user.id}']["level"] = lvl_end
 
@bot.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'You are at level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
```

Answer (score 1):

The json error means that your json file is fully empty and you at least need `{}` in your json file.

Comment: my json doc is like this :
`{"my id": {"experience": 174, "level": 3}}`

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

in a file called users.json
it must look like this:

```
{
  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: my json doc is like this : `{"my id": {"experience": 174, "level": 3}}`

Comment: it must look like this there [...](https://gyazo.com/09632d548c13651647b5752fbc4d2ad3)